# Disable security warning for opening downloaded program files

Tags: firefox

I started getting warnings when attempting to open downloaded jar-files in Firefox today, and I can't figure out how to disable the warning:
[image]
It basically says something like *"x.jar" is a program file, and can contain viruses and stuff. Are you sure you want to open it?*

Yes I am sure, otherwise I wouldn't have downloaded the frigging thing. Looking at the security settings, there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to turn it off, but maybe somewhere here knows a way?

I am using Firefox Quantum 63.0 (64 bit) on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: If you use a fresh Firefox user profile does it happen?

Comment: This is a standard warning message by Windows Defender when opening download files. The question is rather : How have you managed to not get it until now?